# D3.js Text on path not rendered (no height / width)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to render circles which have a text inside, that runs along a given path. 
The markup d3 produces looks fine, but Chrome is not showing the texts. 
Upon inspection it says text elements have 0 width and 0 height.

This is sample markup including only two circles:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 950 600">
  <g>
    <g transform="translate(334.14792673070184,58.96385042366173)">
      <defs>
        <path id="path-1" d="m5,50 a45,45 0 0 0 90,0"></path>
      </defs>
      <circle class="circle" fill="#ccc" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
      <text fill="#333" font-size="15px">
        <textpath xlink:href="#path-1" start-offset="0%">123456</textpath>
      </text>
      <use xlink:href="#path-1" fill="#666" opacity="0.1"></use>
    </g>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(374.66047394649974,371.7948729806046)">
    <defs>
      <path id="path-2" d="m5,50 a45,45 0 0 0 90,0"></path>
    </defs>
    <circle class="circle" fill="#ccc" cx="50" cy="50" r="50"></circle>
    <text fill="#333" font-size="15px">
      <textpath xlink:href="#path-2" start-offset="0%">123456</textpath>
    </text>
    <use xlink:href="#path-2" fill="#666" opacity="0.1"></use>
  </g>
</svg>
```

When I inspect the markup in Chrome console and click "Edit as HTML" on the SVG element, make a random change, save & exit - the SVG suddenly renders correctly.
The exact same thing happens in Firefox and Opera.

Copy pasting the generated markup into a jsfiddle renders everything as expected.
I have tried pulling the < defs > tags out of each individual group into a single global < defs > but it did not solve the problem.
I have also looked at user-agent-stylesheet and other CSS rules that might interfere with rendering.

Is this a problem with how the SVG tag is included and/or the container element's width/height properties? I have been trying different things to fix this for a couple of hours now...

Here is the full SVG markup http://pastebin.com/J2Lz8p23
Here are the relevant parts in my code http://pastebin.com/Bym8kJVN

Comment: textPath with a capital P

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, that did the trick. Not sure if I should laugh or cry now. What a waste of time! :)

Comment: @bendulum Neither laught nor cry, please, just delete the question. There is nothing to learn for others.

Comment: For what it's worth: this post actually solved the same problem for me! I hadn't realised that the textPath tag was case sensitive.